# What conditions do I need if I want to prove a relation which is both symmetric and transitive is also reflexive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, relations

Consider a relation R: A → A which is both symmetric and transitive.

The following proof shows that the relation is also reflexive: Take a ∈ A. If a ∼ b then b ∼ a by symmetry, and hence a ∼ a by transitivity. Therefore, the relation is reflexive."

Is the proof correct or not?

I think it is incorrect. I think it should be "For every a ∈ A, there exists b ∈ A that a ~ b and b ~ a.", not just "Take a ∈ A". After that we can use symmetry and transitivity to prove it is reflexive. That is what I think.

Am I right? Or what is the correct answer and the reason? THANKS!

Comment: There may not be just one $b$ technically, unless the relation is a function . Just a technicality.

Answer (score 2):

The proof is wrong and you are wrong. After all, there are relations which are both symmetric and transitive which are *not* reflexive. Take the empty relation for instance (that is, we never have $a\mathrel Rb$).

However, if you add the hypothesis that for each $a\in A$, there is some $b\in A$ such that $a\mathrel Bb$, then the first proof that you described works.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sim$ is symmetric and transitive, then $a\sim b$ and $b\sim a$ implies $a\sim a$. However, as you say, this presumes the existence of some such $b$. In general, symmetric and transitive do not imply reflexive.

You can make a sort of silly counterexample by just defining $\sim$ on a set. Take the set $\{x,y\}$ and the relation containing only $x\sim x$. This is not reflexive since $y\not\sim y$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why given an $a$ there should be any $b$ which relates to it.

If such a $b$ exists for every $a$ then you are done. But the empty relation on a singleton set (set with one element) is (trivially - there are no cases) symmetric and transitive, but not reflexive.